# iOS development app startup crash

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am currently working an iOS app, nothing serious, just a simple budget tracker. The workflow is the following: coding some new stuff into app => connect my iPhone to my mac => building app with Xcode to my iPhone 6 and my wife's iPhone 6 plus (so two different device!). At this point everything works fine.

But after a while (sometimes just a few days, sometimes weeks), the app suddenly stop working on both devices at the same time, without any foreshadow: We don't update iOS and don't do any changing in the environment, the app just start to do like this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/sized-video-assets-public-v1/wp-content/appadvice-v2-media/2015/07/crash_9b28fddfc26f9f0380f1b0d0b2324018-quarter.gif (but in my case, the app can't reach the first view, crashing immediately after start).

The most weird thing is, the crashing issue starts exactly the same time on both different device, but the "no-problem interval" is never the same: sometimes the crash starts after one day, sometimes after two weeks, etc.
After I rebuild the app to devices with Xcode, the whole thing starts over, and the app works fine for a while.

I already tried these things to debug this problem:

- Fixing all the warnings cased by the Swift's frequent syntax change, so my app always free of warnings => same problem still there
- Checking the diagnostic debug logs on devices, no logs for the time of crashing
- Checking memory usage on startup, its about 25MB on login screen (first view), and the max memory usage is about 38-40MB in the app.
- Debugging app with Xcode, but as I mentioned above, there is no errors/warnings, and after the successful build, the app works fine again.

What is happening here?

Comment: Get your crash logs from the Device and check.

Comment: Shift-command-K (clean). Double check the dev account is hooked up right. Delete and reinstall the app on the device. Make sure the device doesn't come unplugged while running. If the crash is happening while running the app on device but not debugging in Xcode, then there could be a breakpoint or error you're not catching. Worst comes to worst – reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @Santosh As i wrote, I already did that, no crash logs for the time of crashing

Comment: @ShaanSingh Now I found a really weird warning, xcode said my "provisioning profile expiring soon". Its weird, my dev account is paid for January of 2017.

I already reinstalled xcode, when the xcode 7.3 published, the problem was there before and after the reinstall too

Comment: Try logging in and out of your account from Xcode

Comment: Hmm, I did, thank you. Now the "provisioning profile expired soon" error is not showed, maybe this error caused the problem?

Comment: Code signing strikes again 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If application is installed with XCode and you don't have a Paid Program Developer Account, the life expectancy of the app is like 48h approximately

(There is no official time of validity for that)
, for a paid program, it's a few month with the correct certificate. Currently it seems to be approx 60 days.

If you didn't sign your app, it has low life expectancy. It's quite new that Apple allow you to deploy for a free account, but it just for testing purpose (other than simulator), if you want more days to test on device, you have to pay for the developer program.

Hope This will help you...

Do let me know if you have any other query.

Comment: Not sure why you got down voted. This seems like a great answer. Too bad the window is so short. Id like to be able to test my app over the course of several days to see how some of the longer term activities fare. Guess it's time to pony up the cash.